# Selecting Chess player from a pool - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Hii, i have this problem
There are n[even] number of players who want to play chess
How can i get randomize player and opponents ?  [every player will get only one chance]

Think there are 6 player - p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6
I want to do a code which will do such routine for me
p1 vs p5
p2 vs p6
p3 vs p4

Comment: I guess it depends what language you want to do it in.

Comment: the algorithm doesn't really depend on language

Comment: Who is having fun clicking the Down Vote & Close without a reason ! _if you hav a reason then write it_

Comment: nobody is having fun. Not even you. Programmers get frustrated if they can't see the code/show the code. Provide a language tag or a snippet of code... (BTW, I'm not voting here :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a unique random number to every player, sort the player list using that number and select pairs 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 and so on. Should be very fast because of built-in sorting that almost every language has now.

Comment: plz explain a little bit more and with an example

Comment: Here it is in Perl: `sub paired {my @sorted = map $_->[1], sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} map [rand(), $_], @_; my @result; push @result, [shift @sorted, shift @sorted] while 1 < @sorted; return @result;}` And sample usage: `for (paired(1..10)) {print "$_->[0]\t$_->[1]\n"}`

Answer (score 1):

Do [all combinations](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture25.html) and shuffle them [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: But he just wants one combination. So just fill an array with numbers 1 through 6 and do the shuffle. Then players[0] and players[1] play, players[2] and players[3], and players[4] and players[5].

Answer (score 0):

```
store players in array a of size n
let p be a pair(w, b)
let l be a list of pairs
while n > 0
    let x be a random number between 0 and n
    add player at index x in a to p as w
    remove index x from a
    n--
    let y be a random number between 0 and n
    add player at index y in a to p as b
    remove index y from a
    n--
    add p to l
endwhile
```

Comment: I think you want to take a token at random and then shrink the player array ! am i right ?